# Rotating a vector around another vector

Tags: vectors, rotations

[A drawing of what I'd like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTSVR.png)

So given a coordinate system, that has no negative values, the $(0;0)$ is on the upper-left corner, $(X(\max);Y(\max))$ is on the lower-right. I have a $v(v_1;v_2)$ vector, where I know the exact value of $v_1$ and $v_2$. I also know the magnitude of the **$u$** vector, and it's angle to the **$v$** vector.

How can I calculate the $(u_1;u_2)$ coordinates? I can rotate it in a Cartesian system, but not in this one.

Comment: pretend its cartesian everything is negative and your searching for x(min,ymin) its easy to see that this is isomorphic

Comment: This *is* a Cartesian system, albeit a left-handed one. Since you’ve reversed the $y$-axis, reverse the sense of angles, too.

Comment: Use standard rotation formula for 2d-space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix but before that change coordinates frame for the standard one.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say in which direction $u$ is rotated compared to $v$ (clockwise or counterclockwise). Let's say it's counterclockwise, then you calculate $u$ in the following way:

$$
w=
\left( {\matrix{
   {w_1}  \cr 
   {w_2}  \cr
 } } \right)
=
\left( {\matrix{
   {cos(\theta)} & {-sin(-\theta)}  \cr 
   {sin(-\theta)} & {cos(\theta)}  \cr
 } } \right)
\left( {\matrix{
   {v_1}  \cr 
   {v_2}  \cr
 } } \right)
$$

$$
u=\left( {\matrix{
   {u_1}  \cr 
   {u_2}  \cr
 } } \right)=\frac{w}{||w||}||u||
$$
If it's clockwise just use the minus of the angle ($\theta=-\theta$).

I don't think all the axises directions that you mentioned are relevant for solving the problem.